# C - printing system() function output into a file

Tags: c, windows

how can I print the output of `system("dir")` function into a file? in C

Comment: `system("dir > output.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use any special programming. `dir` can be re-directed to a file with

`dir > file.txt`